# Why are missiles rotating in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rocket-science

Watching the Starship launch today I noticed it's actually doing some full rotations. Why isn't it controlled? and why does it happen?

I have read that it's the same for military missiles too

Comment: I cannot confirm this right now but I thought it was so they're uniformly heated by the sun in space.

Comment: Isn't the heat from the sun much smaller than the heat in re-entry? I think the heat shields are designed for the re-entry.

Comment: Was this a roll during launch, or a continual rotation while in orbit?

Comment: Here is an analysis of the Starship rolls. It isn't all intentional. Even so, it was a successful test. [SpaceX Orbit Largest Spacecraft In History also SpaceX Destroy Largest Spacecraft In History.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8htMpR7mnaM)

Answer (score 1):

Some rockets are *spin-stabilized*: they are designed to rotate about their long axis during launch to help them fly straight, the way a bullet does.

Once the rocket has achieved orbit, the payload satellite on top is then detached and *de-spun* so its antennas and solar cells, etc. can be aimed in a specific direction.

The de-spin is achieved by an electric motor whose stator is one end of the satellite and rotor is the other end. turning on that motor in the right direction will then slow down and stop the rotation of the one end (with the antennas and cells) while speeding up the rotation of the other end.

Carefully adjusting the motor current then allows precise *roll control* of the de-spun end.

Comment: I think it was rotating in pitch and yaw too